# How to fix deployment failing to azure deployment slot?

Tags: c#, azure, azure-functions

I have made an Azure function that I deployed with Azure CLI since deployment from Visual studio did not work. But I now added a slot "development" to the Azure fuction and want to deploy my code to this slot. But when I do this I get an error and the deployment fails.

[image]

In the link that is given are no logs.

I used this command:

```
az functionapp deployment source config-zip -g Applications-WE -n \cubigo-dev-alexa --src C:\Users\Joren\stage\Birthday.zip --slot development
```

The command to deploy to the production slot does work:

```
az functionapp deployment source config-zip -g Applications-WE -n \cubigo-dev-alexa --src C:\Users\Joren\stage\Birthday.zip
```

What am I doing wrong?
Thanks in adavance

Answer (score 0):

Go to your azure function and click `Configuration` > `Application settings` and click `Deployment slog setting` for all your application settings like below:

[image]

Comment: Sorry for the late response, I cheched the deployment slot setting box for all settings but WEBSITE_CONTENTAZUREFILECONNECTIONSTRING and WEBSITE_CONTENTSHARE since these couldnt be slot settings but it still gave the same error after saving.

Answer (score 0):

Deployment to the development slot worked when I changed the value from the application setting "WEBSITE_CONTENTSHARE" to the value of the variable in the production slot.